# Setup Cron For a Route in Zend Franework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, cron

I am trying to setup a cron for a rout to send email on specific route defines in my module:

the route is as follows:

```
'company-testing' => array( //Company Invoice Page
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/account/company-testing[/:action]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Company\Controller\CouponOrder',
                    'action' => 'tempTesty',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
        ),
```

My  page url for this route is as follows as per the above configuration:

```
http://shop.projekte-web.com/reisesparer/public/account/company-testing
```

So I have tried to setup the cron through CLI in the following way but it is not working and not sending email with specified cron time.

but if i directly hit the route it generate the email and successfully send it.

CRON SETUP:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /absolute_path_to_my_project/public /account/company-testing > / dev / null 2> & 1
```

Any help regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a console route to get a cron job done with Zend Framework. So if you created the console route that would look like the following

```
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'cron-company-testing' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'cronmail', // route to be used in cli
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Company\Controller\CouponOrder',
                        'action' => 'tempTesty',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Add this above configuration to your `module.config.php`.

First lets check it over the terminal locally. Do the following in your terminal

```
cd /path/to/your/project
php public/index.php cronmail
```

Next up you may add a job to the `crontab`. Please look at the route name, in this case, `cronmail`.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/project/public/index.php cronmail &> /dev/null
```

Now you should check whether that job has added to the `crontab` or not. Use the following command in your terminal

```
crontab -l
```